# Why am I getting no known conversion error?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, std, stdmove

I have such a code:
[Link to Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Krx1ZHgqegMqcr6E)

When I try to compile it I'm getting this:

```
./type_holder.h:45:14: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'test_class'
                return new T(args...);
                           ^ ~~~~
./type_holder.h:54:35: note: in instantiation of member function 'di::DiConstructor<true, test_class, di::DiMark &&, di::AnyResolver>::construct' requested
      here
                                                         decltype(AnyResolver())>::construct(std::move(DiMark{}), AnyResolver{});
                                                                                   ^
test.cc:26:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'di::ConstructIfPossible<test_class>' requested here
        std::cout << di::ConstructIfPossible<test_class>() << std::endl;
                         ^
test.cc:14:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'di::DiMark' to 'di::DiMark &&' for 1st argument
        INJECT(test_class, int* a) {}
               ^
./inject_markers.h:6:36: note: expanded from macro 'INJECT'
#define INJECT(name, ...) explicit name(di::DiMark&& m, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
test.cc:12:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class test_class {
      ^
test.cc:12:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
```

The question is what am I doing wrong? Why does compiler tells me that I'm trying to convert `DiMark` to `DiMark&&`? Should it not be `DiMark&&` already since I did `std::move(DiMark) {}` explicitly converting lvalue to rvalue?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post a [mcve].

Comment: The shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve], without which it cannot be fully analyzed.

Comment: what is `test_class`?

Comment: Updated comment and added link to Wandbox

Comment: Please post problem code in the question, not at an offsite link, so that when your offsite link breaks the question remains of some possible value.

Answer (score 1):

What the errors are telling you is that you're trying to construct a `test_class` object using a two parameter constructor, but you haven't defined any.

There are two constructors, both implicitly defined, that take one parameter (the copy constructor, and the move constructor).  However, since you're trying to construct a `test_class` object with both a `DiMark` and `AnyResolver` arguments, and this constructor does not exist, you get the error.

To resolve this you need to create a two parameter constructor.  (And you then may need to define the copy and move constructors, since the implicit constructors will not be defined if you define any other constructors.)

Comment: I've updated my question and posted link to reproduceble code snippet.